# SimpleAdapter Auto complete

Tags: java, android

O código abaixo é um `adapter` que eu uso para criar um autocomplete no meu aplicativo.

```
mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mPeopleList, R.layout.custcontview ,new String[] { "Name", "Email" }, new int[] { R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontEmail});
```

Esse autocomplete tem o intuito de:

- Mostar Nome
- Mostrar Email

O problema é o seguinte. Ele está funcionando perfeitamente, quando eu começo a digitar ele vai mostrando as opções que minha lista tem para completar corretamente. Porém ele faz a busca pelos dois campos, tanto por nome quanto por email, o que gera uma duplicidade na exibição.

[image]

O quarto e o quinto paramentro ("FROM" "TO") :

```
new String[] { "Name", "Email" }, new int[] { R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontEmail})
```

É onde está o erro de lógica, pois o `FROM` não consigo colocar só 1 campo, se eu fizer isto tenho que declarar só 1 `TO`.

O que eu quero é fazer algo como o seguinte:

```
mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mPeopleList, R.layout.custcontview ,new String[] { "Name"}, new int[] { R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontEmail});
```

Só que dessa forma não cria o Autocomplete.

O que devo fazer para que ele busque (FROM) pelo name e envie os dados para (TO) `ccontName` **e** para `ccontEmail`? Qual solução para este problema?

Comment: Não trabalho com Java mas parece que está tudo bem explicado, só editei os problemas de formatação e ortografia. Fiquei com dúvida na hora de [editar `ccontName EEEE para ccontEmail`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/39483/revisions), acredito que queria simplesmente dar ênfase no **e**; é isso?

Comment: Pois é, parecia código Hexadecimal :p

Comment: faz a verificação antes de exibir no toast

Comment: Como posso fazer isto ? Desculpa, é a primeira vez que estou trabalhando com esse recurso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Boa prática usar constantes para estes valores.
final String NAME = "Name";
final String EMAIL = "Email";

mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mPeopleList, R.layout.custcontview,
        // Defina os campos que deseja utilizar no filtro.
        new String[] { NAME }, new int[] { R.id.ccontName }) {

    // Reimplemente este método para poder configurar
    // os demais campos que não fazem parte do filtro.
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Define os demais campos que irão aparecer na lista.
        final Map<String, String> dataSet = (Map<String, String>) getItem(position);
        String email = dataSet.get(EMAIL);
        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ccontEmail)).setText(email);

        return v;
    }
};
```

Comment: PERFEITO!! Muito obrigado pela ajuda andré !!!!